# How can I LowerCase all the HashMap's values?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` where I'd like to LowerCase every key and value. With the following code, I'm able to do so but the structure of my data changes. How can I possibly fix this?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> t : list.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : t.getValue().entrySet()) {
        lowerCaseList1.put(t.getKey().toLowerCase().trim(), lowerCaseList2.put(e.getValue().toLowerCase().trim(), e.getKey().toLowerCase().trim()));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `Map` in a variable named `list`? That's confusing!!!

Comment: The structure of your data? What does that mean? `HashMap` is unordered. If you want to preserve ordering, use a `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: The most obvious solution is to create a new map with the proper case. In-place alteration means you have a lot of corner cases to work with.

Comment: If you want to convert strings to **UpperCase**, why are you calling **`toLowerCase()`**?

Comment: @Andreas Typo, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert all 3 strings in a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` to uppercase<sup>1</sup>, create a new map.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> input = Map.of("abc", Map.of("Def", "Ghi"),
                                              "jkl", Map.of("MNO", "PQR", "stu", "vwx"));

Map<String,Map<String,String>> output = input.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e1 -> e1.getKey().toUpperCase(),
                e1 -> e1.getValue().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e2 -> e2.getKey().toUpperCase(),
                        e2 -> e2.getValue().toUpperCase()))));

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

```
{abc={Def=Ghi}, jkl={stu=vwx, MNO=PQR}}
{ABC={DEF=GHI}, JKL={STU=VWX, MNO=PQR}}
```

***Note:*** The code will fail with `IllegalStateException: Duplicate key` if there are 2 keys that will become the same when uppercased.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> input = Map.of("aaa", Map.of("bbb", "ccc", "Bbb", "Ccc"));
```

*Output*

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key BBB (attempted merging values CCC and CCC)
```

---

<sup>*1) Question originally asked for uppercase, but has since been changed to ask for lowercase. Leaving answer unchanged, since it doesn't really matter for the purpose of showing how to change casing.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to an elegant solution by @Andreas, you can do it also as follows:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = Map.of("Map1", Map.of("tEst1", "VALUE1", "test2", "VAlue2"), "MaP2",
                Map.of("TEST3", "value3", "Test4", "Value4"));
        System.out.println(map);

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> tempOuter = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> tempInner;

        for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> outerEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            tempInner = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            for (Entry<String, String> innerEntry : outerEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                tempInner.put(innerEntry.getKey().toLowerCase(), innerEntry.getValue().toLowerCase());
            }
            tempOuter.put(outerEntry.getKey().toLowerCase(), tempInner);
        }

        map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        map.putAll(tempOuter);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Map1={test2=VAlue2, tEst1=VALUE1}, MaP2={TEST3=value3, Test4=Value4}}
{map1={test2=value2, test1=value1}, map2={test3=value3, test4=value4}}
```